# How to animate a sprite in WinForms c# to achive projectile motion?

Tags: c#, sprite, simulation, physics, motion

I have already developed the algorithms behind the physics of projectile motion. My **only** problem is drawing on a form.How would I achieve this from scratch.

Comment: you want to know how custom drawing works on a form?

Comment: can you please paste your code vs posting a url link

Comment: @DJKRAZE I dont really have any code at the moment.

Comment: I'm afraid that's a bit too general for stackoverflow. Google it, you'll get plenty of hits. Maybe this is a starting point: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/TheButler/the-basics-of-drawing-graphics-onto-windows-forms/

Comment: search for: winforms custom drawing. hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is a bit too general, but just to shed some light, I think you probably want to create a `PictureBox` control and draw on that, instead of on the actual form that has your controls and settings.

Here's how you create the `Graphics` object for a pictureBox, for example, and then draw a line on it: [Draw a line on PictureBox from parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8947119/draw-a-line-on-picturebox-from-parent)

Now, your simulation, I believe, should actually draw lines, between the newly calculated (x,y) and the previously calculated one, in order to plot a full line instead of just dots, and that will probably happen within a loop in which you vary `t` (time) in intervals.

Comment: Feel free to upvote or accept the answer if it has solved your current problem ;)